# ClickAwayListener not working with Collapse or Fade transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a notifications area. I show a notification icon, and when the user clicks on it, I show the list of notifications.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-breeze-ryktf?file=/src/App.js)

The problem is that I can't mix it with `ClickAwayListener`.

When I use `ClickAwayListener` it's not shown at all.

How should I fix this?

**HeaderAction.js**

```
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

const HeaderAction = ({ icon, title, component }) => {
  const Component = component || (() => <div>NA</div>);

  const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowComponent(!showComponent);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip title={title || ""}>
        <div onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
        </div>
      </Tooltip>

      {/* This part is not working */}
      {/* <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setShowComponent(false)}>
        <div>
          <Fade in={showComponent}>
            <div>
              <Component />
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </div>
      </ClickAwayListener> */}

      <Fade in={showComponent}>
        <div>
          <Component />
        </div>
      </Fade>
    </>
  );
};

export { HeaderAction };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the icon button, `handleClick` is called and the `showComponent` state is set to `true`, but then `onClickAway` from `ClickAwayListener` is also called and set the `showComponent` state to `false` again. The fix is simple, don't let the `onClickAway` handler execute by stopping the propagation after clicking the button:

```
<div
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    handleClick();
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]